# ACE editor rendering error after a put request

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I'm having issues with the ACE editor after a 'put' request to update an object field (using [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browser-enhancements/), which makes use of [Ajax Form](https://github.com/tomchristie/ajax-form) for PUT/PATCH/DELETE/OPTIONS methods).

I'm currently hiding a textarea in a form and replacing with the ace editor, updating the textarea with the editor's content when changed.

However, on put - the following occurs

[image: before submit]

becomes

[image: after submit]

I'm not sure whats going on. It might be that ace/css/ace_editor.css isn't loading, but I'm not sure why this would happen...

Any help would be much appreciated!

```js
     $(function () {
              $('textarea[name=SQL]').each(function () {             
                  console.log('new editor');  
                  $('form').find('textarea[name=SQL]').attr('id','textarea-code');
                  $('#textarea-code').parent().append('<div id="ace-editor" class="ace-editor-class" style="height: auto;min-height:100px"></div>');  
                  var editor = ace.edit("ace-editor"); 
                  editor.setTheme("ace/theme/crimson_editor"); 
                  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/sql");  
                  var textarea = $('#textarea-code').css('display', 'none'); 
                  editor.getSession().setValue(textarea.val());  
                  editor.getSession().on('change', function(){
                    textarea.val(editor.getSession().getValue()); 
                    editor.resize(true); 
                  });
              });
            });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "after a http put request", and "on put"? Which resource is being "putted"? Is this HTML in the HTTP PUT request?

Comment: updated the question with more info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Temporary solution:**
It seems the editor is missing some vital css (.ace_editor). Solution is to copy line 14388 of ace.js:

```
var editorCss = ".ace_editor {\ ...
```

into a local css file (removing all \ first).

Comment: looks like after put request something removes the style tag that ace have added for editorCss